# Google Cloud SQL doesnt works when exported

Tags: mysql, gcloud

I can't access to google sql instance. I made a export operation and it doesn't finish it. I can't access with phpmyadmin. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: My Spanish is not good but your operations log seems showing the last try to export Cloud SQL succeeded. For the second issue, can you post the error messages that you're receiving when trying to access to your SQL instance using phpMyAdmin?  Did you authorize your remote IP address and configure a user account for your access? I recommend  visiting this article: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/getting-started?hl=en#configure

Comment: The problem was that i had a lot of connections active in that moment. When i killed all of them it worked perfect :)